# How to load UITableView having separate subclass for delegate and data Source?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

There is one `UIViewController` consisting of an `UITextField` and an `UITableView`. I have a separate subclass of `UIViewTableViewController` that is used to support delegation and data source for the `UITableView` in `UIViewController`(default). I can get the text from `UITexField` into SecondViewController and save it to `NSMutableArray`, but that is not passing on to `UITableView`.  If I just pass a string to *cell, it shows in `UITableView`.
Here is the code:

**ViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SecondTableViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
        SecondTableViewController *tableController;
    }
    @end

**ViewController.m**

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableController = [[SecondTableViewController alloc] init];
    tableController.taskArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.table.dataSource = tableController;
    self.table.delegate = tableController;
    self.textField.delegate = tableController;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**SecondTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property NSMutableArray *taskArray;
@property NSString *taskString;


@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation SecondTableViewController


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.taskString = [textField text];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self.taskArray addObject:self.taskString];
    [textField setText:@""];
    NSLog(@"array is %@", self.taskArray);
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self
                                             .self.taskArray.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:
    UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.taskArray.count;
    }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
                }
        cell.textLabel.text = self.taskArray[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"cell ident %@", self.taskArray[indexPath.row]);

    return cell;
}




@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your reference to tableView in SecondTableViewController is not pointing to the `tableView` var that you made in the original UIViewController so cellForRowAtIndexPath wouldn't be doing anything with that `tableView` var.

The TableViewController class has a property called `tableView` that comes already binded to the class with a reference to its parent and then that class being the delegate and datasource.  You have broken the linkage to the delegate and datasource but not to the tableView property itself.

If you want to separate the delegate and the datasource from the class with which the `tableview` resides then you can do that but you don't need to use a UITableViewController class.  You could make a custom class subclassing NSObject and include all of those delegate and datasource calls in there.  If you did that then your code for setting the delegate and datasource of tableView would look like this

```
 SeparateDataSourceClass *separateClass = [SeparateDataSourceClass new];
 self.table.dataSource = separateClass;
 self.table.delegate = separateClass;
 self.textField.delegate = separateClass;
```

Something like that but you probably get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you doing this way. I mean View Controller 2 is controlling the look and feel of View Controller 1!!! You do not do it this way!

However, your problem is that `self.tableView` in `SecondTableViewController` is not the table view for which you had set it the delegate. `self.tableView` in `SecondTableViewController` is the default table view that it is getting for being a sub class for `UITableViewController`.

To fix this there are couple of solutions:

**Solution 1:** Get rid of this messy view hierarchy and have same view controller
    manage the stuff.

**Solution 2:** Call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` on right table view object. To do that you may pass `tableView` reference from `ViewController` to `SecondTableViewController`.